# Why does $\frac{\partial a^TX a}{\partial X} = aa^T$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, partial-derivative

$$\frac{\partial a^TX a}{\partial X} =  \frac{\partial a^TX^T a}{\partial X} = aa^T \tag 1$$

I got (1) from the Matrix Cookbook. But I don't see how you derive it? Why isn't it $a^Ta$.

Assume that $a$ is an arbitrary vector of real numbers of length $n$ and $X$ is an arbitrary $n\times n$ matrix.

Comment: I don't understand what is a partial derivative w.r.t. a matrix.

Comment: @Bernard : Maybe you should make that a question. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 3):

Write out $a^TXa$ by component:

$$
a^TXa = \sum_{ij} a_ix_{ij}a_j
$$

Realize that $\frac{\partial}{\partial X}$ is shorthand for the matrix composed of entries  $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{ij}}$. Therefore,

$$
\frac{\partial a^TXa}{\partial x_{ij}} = a_ia_j
$$

Stack these into a matrix, and this is exactly $aa^T$. Why not $a^Ta$? Just look at the dimensions! :)

Answer (score 1):

A more general result is as follows.  Let $M:=\text{Mat}_{n\times n}(\mathbb{R})$.  Define $f:M\to \mathbb{R}$ to be $f(X)=\text{trace}(AX)$ for some fixed $A \in M$.  Then, $$\frac{\partial}{\partial X}\,f(X)=A^\top\,.$$  In this particular case, $A=aa^\top$, so $f(X)=\text{trace}\left(aa^\top X\right)=\text{trace}\left(a^\top Xa\right)=a^\top Xa$.  Hence, $$\frac{\partial}{\partial X}\,\left(a^\top X a\right)=\left(aa^\top\right)^\top =aa^\top\,.$$

Comment: there is a typo at the end $a^\top a$ instead of $aa^\top$

Comment: @user251257.  Thanks, fixed.